2SXC - Inner Content Block Unique Identifier
In 2sxc, when embedding a separate app as inner content within a WYSIWYG Rich input, the rendered inner app's context returns the parent's ModuleID.
This can be demonstrated using 2sxc's Blog app when embedding any other app in an article's description field where the returned ModuleID is of the parent module.
This presents an issue where the data from an embedded app utilizes the ModuleID for filtering. There doesn't seem to be any other context-related unique sub-filter properties available to use such as the parent's EntityID or ContentBlockID when it is rendered in the app (e.g. the value used on the "data-cb-id" attribute on the "sc-content-block" wrapper for the content block).
We're reviewed the 2sxc documentation and tried referring to values such as CmsContext.Block.Id and others accessible in the inner app, but none seem to return a suitable unique value either.
We've temporarily solved this as others have mentioned in the Blog app by adding an item sub-filter using the article's URL snippet but this isn't a reliable long-term approach if they are changed.
TLDR; Is there any way to get a unique identifier for an inner content app in the context of the parent within a razor template?
FYI: We're running the latest version of DNN (v9.13.3), 2sxc (v17.07) and v6.17 of the Blog app.

I'm going to guess what you're trying to do: You probably have a blog, and on some of the blog-posts (same ModuleId) you have inner-content showing another app, which shows a data extract or something. Could you revise your question, provide more details etc.?

@iJungleBoy Thank you for responding. We attempted to clarify the issue further. Hope that helps and as a community, we appreciate all your efforts to help advance the DNN community!

You're in luck, it's there but not documented yet, but could also be improved a bit.
CmsContext.Block.Id does return the value you need. I believe it's been working since ca. v14 but was never publicly documented. I'll correct that asap.
Note that CmsContext.Module.Block.Id also works, but that will return the block-id of the root block.
I will also add a .Guid in 17.08 because the ID may change if you export/import the app, while the Guid will remain stable.
ok?

Thank you for the reply @iJungleBoy. We looked through all the exposed properties returned from CmsContext in the inner content module before posting this question.
The CmsContext.Block.Id returns 0 when we view it in Visual Studio running 2SXC v17.7 and some earlier versions.

This may be an edge case, where the block was not created yet. Background is that a block can be temporary - allowing the user to still switch to showing another app, in which case the block doesn't exist yet. It usually becomes permanent, once edit or a similar action is used on the block.

Is it possible you can generate something unique based on MyContext.Block? I haven't tried it in this context, but my understanding is that Kit.Key.UniqueKeyWith(MyContext.Block) should provide a unique identifier. This assumes the block is not null or something.
Anyhow, I thought it might be worth a try if you still don't have a way forward.
